# Post on Facebook Page from iOS App Not Showing Up on Page?

Tags: facebook

I am posting a picture and dummy text on a facebook page with the Page Id "848190045198980".I am signing in using my facebook credentials.Also I have admin role for the specific page.So I am just getting the basic permissions from facebook.Below is the request and the response.

**Request :**

UIImage * productImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"corporate.png"];
NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(productImage);

NSDictionary *params = @{@"message": @"Hello XYZ", @"source":imageData};

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/848190045198980/photos" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    
    if(!error)
    {
        if(completionBlock)
        {
            
            NSLog(@"%@",result);
            completionBlock(YES,result,nil);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(completionBlock)
            completionBlock(NO,nil,error);
    }
}];
```

**Response :**
{"id":"1481175438805031","post_id":"848190045198980_1481175438805031"}

**Expected Result :** My Post should show up on the Facebook Page in "Posts to Page" Section.

**Actual Result :** Nothing Shows Up.

Please point me in the right direction as to what I am missing here.I have checked the API Doc several times and I am finding it real tough as to where I am missing something.

Regards,
Roman

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am posting video on Facebook:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"message":message,
                         @"tags":Mystring,
                         @"link":@"http://www.miimobileapp.com/website/index.html",
                         @"privacy": @"{'value': 'SELF'}",

                         };
/* make the API call */
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:@"/me/feed"
                              parameters:params
                              HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,id result,NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Post successful");
}
```