# Post comment on facebook in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to comment on the Facebook post from the application with the following method:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"message": @"test message",
                             @"access_token": [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken].tokenString,
                             @"app_id": @"1288902784652019",
                             @"app_secret": @"bhjijsidjeiwdjdjjkrhecb232ff3020"
                             };
// 81 is the post id
    FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:@"/81"
                                  parameters:params
                                  HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"result..%@",result);
        NSLog(@"error..%@",error);
        // Handle the result
    }];
```

I am getting following response:

```
body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 240;
            "fbtrace_id" = E4HZyWR32MY;
            message = "(#240) Requires a valid user to be specified (either via the session or via the API parameter for specifying the user.";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 403;
}}
```

Can anybody advice me what I am doing wrong. Or is there any other way to post the comment. Please advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you log the user in and have them grant the necessary permissions to your app? Do you even have a user access token here? Sounds like it might just be falling back to the app token.

Comment: Yes, I have successfully logged in with these granted permissions @@[@"email", @"public_profile", @"user_likes", @"publish_actions"]

Comment: If you want to create a comment, then you must post to `/object-id/comments`, not just to `/object-id`

Comment: @CBroe I already tried with /object-id/comments

Comment: this answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889491/post-on-facebook-page-from-ios-app-not-showing-up-on-page/31740226#31740226